# How to automatically upload files to a website using python

Tags: javascript, python, web, web-scraping, request

I've built an app using streamlit which recieves a csv file and returns another csv file. I need to automatically upload files using python. Here is the link to the app:
https://maalaei97-test3.hf.space/?__theme=light

I use requests.post(URL, data) but I keep receiving response 405, which says that the method is not allowed. I should mention that since I use the python script inside a software which only supports Iron Python, I do not have access to libraries like Beautifulsoap and Selenium

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where are you storing your data and how? The place in which you are storing your data; do they have an API that specifies how to send file objects via their API?